# Reading a json object and removing some values

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON object with following structure:

```json
{
    "org_name": "1",
    "available": True,
    "orgs": [
        {
            "org_name": "2",
            "available": False,
            "orgs": []
        },
        {
            "org_name": "3",
            "available": False,
            "orgs": []
        },
        {
            "org_name": "4",
            "available": True,
            "orgs": []
        },
        {
            "org_name": "5",
            "available": False,
            "orgs": [
                {
                    "org_name": "6",
                    "available": False,
                    "orgs": []
                },
                {
                    "org_name": "7",
                    "available": False,
                    "orgs": []
                },
                {
                    "org_name": "8",
                    "available": False,
                    "orgs": [
                        {
                            "org_name": "9",
                            "available": False,
                            "orgs": []
                        },
                        {
                            "org_name": "10",
                            "available": True,
                            "orgs": []
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to parse this JSON data and get a output similar to this:

```json
{
  "org_name": "1",
  "orgs": [
    {
      "org_name": "4",
      "orgs": []
    },
    {
      "org_name": "5",
      "orgs": [
        {
          "org_name":"8",
           "orgs":[
           {
           "org_name":"10"
           }
         ]
        }
      ]
    }
}
```

The conditions are:

- If `available` is `True` the output should contain it's `org_name` and it's `orgs`;
- If `available` is `False` then it should be removed;
- If a child `org` has it's `available` `True` than full parent org should be present.

I am having a hard time finding a logic to get a output.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Can you include the code you have tried so far.

Comment: You need to write recursive function that will parse/traverse non-empty `orgs` keys

Comment: why `"org_name":"4"` is the parent of `"org_name":"5"` in the output *JSON* while in the input they are siblings?

Comment: @NimaAfshar Sorry a mistake .. i have corrected it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write simple recursive function which will check your JSON object if it's available or any of it's child nodes is available:

```py
def filter_orgs(source):
    orgs = [org for o in source["orgs"] if (org := filter_orgs(o))]
    if orgs or source["available"]:
        return {
            "org_name": source["org_name"], 
            "orgs": orgs
        }
```

Usage:

```py
source = {
    "org_name": "1",
    "available": True,
    "orgs": [
        {
            "org_name": "2",
            "available": False,
            "orgs": []
        },
        {
            "org_name": "3",
            "available": False,
            "orgs": []
        },
        {
            "org_name": "4",
            "available": True,
            "orgs": []
        },
        {
            "org_name": "5",
            "available": False,
            "orgs": [
                {
                    "org_name": "6",
                    "available": False,
                    "orgs": []
                },
                {
                    "org_name": "7",
                    "available": False,
                    "orgs": []
                },
                {
                    "org_name": "8",
                    "available": False,
                    "orgs": [
                        {
                            "org_name": "9",
                            "available": False,
                            "orgs": []
                        },
                        {
                            "org_name": "10",
                            "available": True,
                            "orgs": []
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

filtered_source = filter_orgs(source)
```

Output:

```py
{
    "org_name": "1",
    "orgs": [
        {
            "org_name": "4",
            "orgs": []
        },
        {
            "org_name": "5",
            "orgs": [
                {
                    "org_name": "8",
                    "orgs": [
                        {
                            "org_name": "10",
                            "orgs": []
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

---

**Upd.** You can also implement in-place modification of dictionary:

```py
def filter_orgs_inplace(source):
    available = source.pop("available")
    for i in range(len(orgs := source["orgs"]) - 1, -1, -1):
        if not filter_orgs_inplace(orgs[i]):
            del orgs[i]
        else:
            available = True
    if not available:
        source.clear()
    return available
```

Usage:

```
source = {
    "org_name": "1",
    "available": True,
    "orgs": [
        {
            "org_name": "2",
            "available": False,
            "orgs": []
        },
        {
            "org_name": "3",
            "available": False,
            "orgs": []
        },
        {
            "org_name": "4",
            "available": True,
            "orgs": []
        },
        {
            "org_name": "5",
            "available": False,
            "orgs": [
                {
                    "org_name": "6",
                    "available": False,
                    "orgs": []
                },
                {
                    "org_name": "7",
                    "available": False,
                    "orgs": []
                },
                {
                    "org_name": "8",
                    "available": False,
                    "orgs": [
                        {
                            "org_name": "9",
                            "available": False,
                            "orgs": []
                        },
                        {
                            "org_name": "10",
                            "available": True,
                            "orgs": []
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

filter_orgs_inplace(source)  # modifies source
```

Output:

```py
{
    "org_name": "1",
    "orgs": [
        {
            "org_name": "4",
            "orgs": []
        },
        {
            "org_name": "5",
            "orgs": [
                {
                    "org_name": "8",
                    "orgs": [
                        {
                            "org_name": "10",
                            "orgs": []
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```